# get_the_terms return only last term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

In my custom post type (portfolio_pt) I have some hierarchical category structure something like that:

```
ParentCat
|-child
    |-someItem
ParentCat2
|-cild
...
```

When I try to get list of all terms by get_the_terms function for "someItem" post this function return only last category ("Child Cat" without "Parent Cat") example:

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_pt_category' );
```

I try to use get_the_term_list function but effect is the same, it returns only last category.

Thanks for help!

Comment: How are you attempting to output `$terms`?

Comment: Just print_r the array and I have only last category in array
`Array
(
    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 9
            [name] => Webdesign
            [slug] => webdesign
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 9
            [taxonomy] => portfolio_pt_category
            [description] => with Parent
            [parent] => 27
            [count] => 7
            [object_id] => 632
            [filter] => raw
        )

)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `get_the_terms` try using [`get_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) and set the hierarchal argument to true. Also make sure you show empty so you are not hiding your empty categories.

Try something like this:

```
$args = array(
'hide_empty'    => false,
'hierarchical'    => true
); 
$terms = get_terms('portfolio_pt', $args);

foreach($terms as $term)
    echo $term->name;
```

Comment: this return all taxonomys but I need only for directed post.

Comment: this does not return all taxonomies. it will only return the portfolio_pt taxonomy.

Comment: yes but for all posts not only for directed post_id